# JTable not refreshed after mixing Row Header and combine/split code.

Tags: java, swing, jtable, custom-component, rowheader

I am working in a project in which I have to show Row Numbers along with the functionality to Combine/Split cells in a JTable. To implement this functionality I followed the code from the url:-

1.) RowNumberHeader -> http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/18/row-number-table/

Then I followed the code to Combine/Split cells:-

http://www.java3z.com/cwbwebhome/article/article5/swing_example/JTableExamples4.html

After integration of the above code It looks like:-

```
package com.test.jtable;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

/**
 * @version 1.0 11/22/98
 */
public class MixedExample extends JFrame {

  public MixedExample() {
    super( "Mixed Example" ); 

    AttributiveCellTableModel ml = new AttributiveCellTableModel(100,5) {
      public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) { 
        return "" + row + ","+ col; 
      }
    };
    CellAttribute cellAtt = ml.getCellAttribute();
    MultiSpanCellTable table = new MultiSpanCellTable( ml );
    table.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
    table.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class ,new AttributiveCellRenderer());

    JTable jRowTable = new RowNumberTable(table);
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    scroll.setRowHeaderView(jRowTable);
    scroll.setCorner(scroll.UPPER_LEFT_CORNER,jRowTable.getTableHeader());
    scroll.setSize(300,300);

    ColorPanel colorPanel = new ColorPanel(table,(ColoredCell)cellAtt);
    FontPanel   fontPanel = new FontPanel(table, (CellFont)cellAtt);
    SpanPanel   spanPanel = new SpanPanel(table, (CellSpan)cellAtt);
    Box boxAtt = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    boxAtt.add(colorPanel);
    boxAtt.add(fontPanel);
    boxAtt.add(spanPanel);

    Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
    box.add(scroll);
    box.add(new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL));
    box.add(boxAtt);
    getContentPane().add( box );
    setSize( 400, 300 );
    setVisible(true);
  }

  class ColorPanel extends JPanel {
    JTable table;
    ColoredCell cellAtt;
    ColorPanel(final JTable table, final ColoredCell cellAtt) {
      this.table   = table;
      this.cellAtt = cellAtt;
      setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Color"));
      JButton b_fore   = new JButton("Foreground");
      b_fore.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          changeColor(true);
        }
      });
      JButton b_back   = new JButton("Background");
      b_back.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          changeColor(false);
        }
      });
      JPanel p_buttons = new JPanel();
      add(b_fore);
      add(b_back);
    }

    private final void changeColor(boolean isForeground) {
      int[] columns = table.getSelectedColumns();
      int[] rows    = table.getSelectedRows();
      if ((rows == null) || (columns == null)) return;
      if ((rows.length<1)||(columns.length<1)) return;
      Color target    = cellAtt.getForeground(rows[0], columns[0]);
      Color reference = cellAtt.getBackground(rows[0], columns[0]);
      for (int i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
        int row = rows[i];
        for (int j=0;j<columns.length;j++) {
      int column = columns[j];
      target    = (target    != cellAtt.getForeground(row, column)) ?
        null : target;
      reference = (reference != cellAtt.getBackground(row, column)) ?
        null : reference;
        }
      }
      String title;
      if (isForeground) {
        target    = (target   !=null) ? target    : table.getForeground();
        reference = (reference!=null) ? reference : table.getBackground();
        title = "Foreground Color";
      } else {
        target    = (reference!=null) ? reference : table.getBackground();
        reference = (target   !=null) ? target    : table.getForeground();
        title = "Foreground Color";
      } 
      TextColorChooser chooser =
        new TextColorChooser(target, reference, isForeground);
      Color color = chooser.showDialog(MixedExample.this,title);
      if (color != null) {  
        if (isForeground) {
      cellAtt.setForeground(color, rows, columns);
        } else {
      cellAtt.setBackground(color, rows, columns);
        }
        table.clearSelection();
        table.revalidate();
        table.repaint();      
      }
    }
  }

  class FontPanel extends JPanel {
    String[] str_size  = {"10","12","14","16","20"};
    String[] str_style = {"PLAIN","BOLD","ITALIC"};
    JComboBox name,style,size;

    FontPanel(final JTable table, final CellFont cellAtt) {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Font"));
      Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
      JPanel p2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
      JPanel p3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,1));
      JPanel p4 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
      p2.add(new JLabel("Name:"));
      p2.add(new JLabel("Style:"));    
      p2.add(new JLabel("Size:"));
      Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
      name  = new JComboBox(toolkit.getFontList());
      style = new JComboBox(str_style);
      size  = new JComboBox(str_size);
      size.setEditable(true);
      JButton b_apply   = new JButton("Apply");
      b_apply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          int[] columns = table.getSelectedColumns();
          int[] rows    = table.getSelectedRows();
          if ((rows == null) || (columns == null)) return;
          if ((rows.length<1)||(columns.length<1)) return;
          Font font = new Font((String)name.getSelectedItem(),
                              style.getSelectedIndex(),
              Integer.parseInt((String)size.getSelectedItem()));
          cellAtt.setFont(font, rows, columns);
          table.clearSelection();
          table.revalidate();
          table.repaint();    
        }
      });
      p3.add(name);
      p3.add(style);
      p3.add(size);
      p4.add(BorderLayout.CENTER,b_apply);
      box.add(p2);
      box.add(p3);
      add(BorderLayout.CENTER,box);
      add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, p4);
    }
  }

  class SpanPanel extends JPanel {
    JTable table;
    CellSpan cellAtt;
    SpanPanel(final JTable table, final CellSpan cellAtt) {
      this.table   = table;
      this.cellAtt = cellAtt;
      setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
      setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Span"));
      JButton b_one   = new JButton("Combine");
      b_one.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      int[] columns = table.getSelectedColumns();
      int[] rows    = table.getSelectedRows();
      cellAtt.combine(rows,columns);
      table.clearSelection();
      table.revalidate();
      table.repaint();
        }
      });
      JButton b_split = new JButton("Split");
      b_split.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      int column = table.getSelectedColumn();
      int row    = table.getSelectedRow();
      cellAtt.split(row,column);
      table.clearSelection();
      table.revalidate();
      table.repaint();
        }
      });
      add(b_one);
      add(b_split);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    MixedExample frame = new MixedExample();
    frame.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
      public void windowClosing( WindowEvent e ) {
        System.exit(0);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

On scrolling it shows blank white rows as below:-

[image]

I tried with several things like adjust row height and column width in MultiSpanCellTable
But after this it is not visible for large number of rows.

Please feel free to share your ideas related with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement code that updates your JPanels? I haven't really coded things this complicated, but I hope this might help you in some way. Maybe try repainting it after you scroll.

Comment: I tried using Adjustment listener for my JScrollPane with the below code:- 

public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
   table.clearSelection();
   table.revalidate();
   table.repaint();   
   this.repaint();
}

But after the above code on scrolllbar scroll table doesn't get repainted.

Answer (score 0):

By implementing the code based on repainting. I added the code for listening change events on ViewPort as below:-

```
jScrollPane.getViewport().addChangeListener(this);

public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.repaint();
        jTable.revalidate();
        jTable.repaint();
        jTable.updateUI();
    }
```

This is also not working it fixes the issue but removes the GUI to split/combine cells.